# How to use うちに with potential form verbs

Tags: grammar

From my textbook, I learned that I have to use verbs in ている form or potential form when using ~うちに grammar point. However, I am not sure if I should use potential form or ている form in this example.

'While I can still travel'

Should I use 旅行できるうちに or 旅行しているうちに？Or are they both incorrect?

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1):

So meanings are different.

旅行できるうちに is *while I can travel*

旅行しているうちに is *while I'm traveling*

Pick the one that matches your situation best.

Comment: Thank you so much!